# HTML Outlook 2013 email exceeding 100% width of panel width width="100%" set

Tags: html, outlook, outlook-2013

I'm trying to create a responsive HTML email for **Outlook 2013** but I'm having trouble  trying to get the email to respect the width limit I have set (i.e. width="100%"). The actual width is indeed being set to 100% until I reach a certain smaller width at which point I have to scroll to view the information.

The code works fine in IE (no surprise) so I know the code itself is at least appropriate in that sense (i.e. I haven't wrapped something incorrectly).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
    <title>Responsive Email Template</title>
    <style type="text/css">
       .ReadMsgBody {
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #ffffff;
       }

       .ExternalClass {
         width: 100%; 
         background-color: #ffffff;
       }

       body {
         width: 100%;
         background-color: #ffffff;
         margin:0;
         padding:0;
         -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
         font-family: Georgia, Times, serif
       }

       table {
         border-collapse: collapse;
       }

       a {
         color:#0076b7;
       }

       .nav-link:visited {
         color:#fff;
       }
/*
       @media only screen and (max-width: 640px)  {
         .deviceWidth {width:440px!important; padding:0;}
         .ReadMsgBody {width:440px!important; padding:0;}
         .center {text-align: center!important;}
       }

       @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
         .deviceWidth {width:280px!important; padding:0;}
         .ReadMsgBody {width:280px!important; padding:0;}
          .center {text-align: left!important;}
       } */

    </style>
</head>
<body style="font-family: Georgia, Times, serif">

    <!-- Wrapper -->
    <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <tr>
            <td bgcolor="#fff" style="padding-top:20px" valign="top" width="100%">

                <!-- Start Header-->
                <table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="deviceWidth" style="font-size:21px; font-weight:bold; margin:0 auto; font-family:'Franklin Gothic',sans-serif;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#0076B7" width="100%">

                            <!-- Logo -->
                            <table align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="deviceWidth">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="center" style="line-height:32px; padding:5px 20px;">
                                        <a class="nav-link" style="font-size:21px; font-weight:bold; color:#fff; text-decoration: none; font-family:'Franklin Gothic',sans-serif;" href="#">LOGO</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table><!-- End Logo -->

                            <!-- Nav -->
                            <table align="right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="deviceWidth">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="center" style="font-size: 13px; color: #fff; font-weight: light; text-align: right; font-family:'Franklin Gothic Book',sans-serif; line-height: 24px; vertical-align: middle; padding:10px 20px; font-style:normal">
                                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">Home</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">News</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">Events</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">Applications</a> &nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #fff;">OrgChart</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table><!-- End Nav -->

                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><!-- End Header -->

                <!-- Actual Email Section -->
                <table align="center" bgcolor="#fff" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="deviceWidth" style="margin:0 auto;" width="100%">
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#fff" style="font-size: 16px; color: #292215; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; line-height: 24px; vertical-align: top; padding:10px 8px 10px 8px">
                            <table>
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="padding:10px 10px 10px 0" valign="middle">
                                        <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #004467; font-size: 32px; font-weight: normal; font-family:'Franklin Gothic', sans-serif">Title</a>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>

                            <!-- Content -->
                            <p>Content here.</p>
                        </td>
                    </tr>

                    <!-- Footer -->
                    <tr>
                        <td bgcolor="#fff" style="font-size: 16px; color: #292215; font-weight: normal; text-align: left; font-family: Georgia, Times, serif; line-height: 24px; vertical-align: top; padding:40px 8px 10px 8px">
                            <a href="#" style="font-size:18px; text-decoration: none;font-family: 'Franklin Gothic', sans-serif;">Place of Work</a><br>
                            Jacob Johnson<br>
                            Work Role<br>
                            <a href="mailto:me@me.com">jacobjohnson@me.com</a><br>
                            555-555-5555
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table><!-- End One Column -->

            </td>
        </tr>
    </table><!-- End Wrapper -->

    <div style="display:none; white-space:nowrap; font:15px courier; color:#ffffff;">
        - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Recap: My email extends beyond the width limit I have it set for and I can't figure out why. Outlook is a pain in my butt.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook isn't broken, your code exhibits the same behavior in almost every email client.

The problem is that you set all the tables to have a width of 100%. On many of them, you added the class .deviceWidth, where you specify the width in media queries, but not for anything wider than 640px. Outlook does not support @media queries.

Try adding `.deviceWidth {width:440px!important; padding:0;}` to your style sheet outside of media queries and address your `width="100%"` on every table.

JSFiddle is not working for me right now so I can't show you a sample.

Good luck.

Comment: That has the same behavior in Outlook but limits the size of my content to 480px in any browser.

Comment: Then set the value of `.deviceWidth` to whatever size you like. I am trying to help explain why your code does not work as expected with any email client.

Comment: The email views fine in Gmail and Hotmail as tested. Outlook is the only one where I'm unable to scale the content.

Comment: I just checked again and your email looks like crap in Gmail. It has a black background instead of white. In Outlook.com, it's missing content and is poorly formatted. It's too wide in iPhone 5, 6. It's broken in other email clients, but I'll let you figure out how, since you're unwilling to take advice.  I tested your code using Litmus to give you an assessment of what I see as being broken to help you out. I don't have a secret agenda. I'm done.

Comment: I didn't mean to tug a heart string, buddy. In any case, it now works appropriately on all our needed clients including gmail and outlook. I don't know what to tell you. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Outlook doesn't respect 100% width so you need to set a fixed width for outlook, add width to the wrapper table

```
<table class="for_others" align="center" border="0" 
cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
```

And using the class set width to 100% for all others. Use !important at the end of the declaration to override inline css.

```
table.for_others {width: 100% !important;}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get the same behavior even after manually replacing all 100% widths to a specific width. Outlook demands a minimum size of like 800px (?) but scales up from that just fine. Thanks.